Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{\sinh(x \frac{\pi}2)} \mathrm dx$
Context (not necessary)
The even Bernoulli numbers can be computed as
$$
B_{2n} = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{\cosh(x \frac{\pi}2)} \mathrm dx.
$$
Playing around with this, I wondered "what if we turned evens to odds", and found an integral
$$
I_n =  \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx.
$$
Interestingly, it appears that every $I_n$ is an integer: computer approximations give $I_1 = 1, I_2 = 2, I_3 = 16, I_4 = 272, I_5 = 7936, ...$ which matches the tangent numbers (coefficients of the E.G.F. of $\tan(x)$).
Question
Computer algebra approximations give
$$
I_3 = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx = 16.
$$
How can we show this algebraically?
I attempted rewriting $\sinh(x)$ in exponential form and some other manipulations to no luck.  WolframAlpha is able to find an antiderivative as a long messy combination of polylogarithms, but is unable to exactly evaluate the definite integral.

Using the exponential form,
$$
I_3
= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{e^{\pi x/2} - e^{-\pi x/2}} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Multiply the top and bottom by $e^{-\pi x/2}$:
$$
I_3
= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^5 e^{-\pi x/2} }{1 - e^{-\pi x}} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Expand in a geometric series:
$$\begin{align*}
I_3
&= 2 \int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-\pi x/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi n x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^5 e^{-\pi x/2}e^{-\pi n x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^5 \exp \left( - \pi x \left( n + \frac 1 2 \right) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}$$
Substitute $u := \pi (n+\frac 1 2) x$. Out of laziness, I'm letting $a := \pi (n+\frac 1 2)$ henceforth.
$$\begin{align*}
I_3
&= 2  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a^6} \int_0^\infty 
    u^5 e^{-u}
     \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}$$
The integral here is trivially $120$:
$$\begin{align*}
I_3
&= 240 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a^6} \\
&= \frac{240}{\pi^6} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+\frac 1 2)^6} \\
\end{align*}$$
Multiply the top and bottom of the sum by $2^6$ to get some a tad more reasonable:
$$\begin{align*}
I_3
&= \frac{240 \cdot 2^6}{\pi^6} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6} \\
\end{align*}$$
The sum that remains is a fairly standard result for Fourier analysis students to investigate, or follows easily from the Riemann zeta function.

Fourier Approach: The Fourier series of $x(\pi -|x|)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ is given by
$$
\frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n + 1) x)}{(2n + 1)^3}
$$
Parseval's theorem tells us that, if $f$ has a Fourier sine-cosine series in coefficients $a_n,b_n$, then
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f^2(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac 1 2 a_0^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^2 + b_n^2)
$$
Here, $a_n = \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}$ and $b_n = 0$. So the right hand side of the above identity becomes the series we seek; the left side becomes an easy integral.


Riemann $\zeta$ Approach: We simply note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}
+ \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^6}}_{=\zeta(6)/2^6}
= \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6}}_{=\zeta(6)}
$$
i.e.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^6}
= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^6} \right) \zeta(6)
$$
This works fine provided you're willing to take for granted the result for $\zeta(2n)$:
$$
\zeta(2n) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (2\pi)^{2n}}{2 \cdot (2n)!} B_{2n}
$$
The upshots are that this is easier to generalize to other $I_n$, and displays more of a relationship to the Bernoulli numbers.

Either way:
One should conclude the result of $\frac{\pi^6}{960}$. So
$$
I_3
=  \frac{240 \cdot 2^6}{\pi^6} \cdot \frac{\pi^6}{960}
= 16
$$
as desired.

Wow that was quick. And that's where the connection to the tangent numbers comes from too! Great answer!

Appreciate very much your detailed writing and effort! Most people would've omitted explaining how to get the sum after saying that it's doable using standard methods. I'm sure this will help someone :)

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{\pi x}{2}=t\to \,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\,dt\implies x=\frac{2}{\pi}t}$$
$$I=\frac{64}{\pi^6}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^5}{\sinh(t)} \mathrm dt$$
$$\color{red}{\sinh(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}}$$
Here's the continuation to rewriting $\sinh (t)$ in exponential form
$$I=\frac{128}{\pi^6}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^5}{e^t-e^{-t}} \mathrm dt$$
$$I=\frac{128}{\pi^6}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^5e^{-t}}{1-e^{-2t}} \mathrm dt$$
$$\color{red}{2t=x\implies \,dt=\frac12\,dx\to t=\frac12 x}$$
$$I=\frac{2}{\pi^6}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{1-e^{-x}} \mathrm dx$$
From here,
$$\color{blue}{\displaystyle \zeta (s,a)\,\Gamma (s)=\int _{0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{s-1}e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}}dx\tag1}$$
On comparing,
$$s=6,a=\frac12$$
$${I=\frac{2}{\pi^6}\zeta\left(6,\frac12\right)\Gamma(6)=16}$$
$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx=16}$$
The generalization would be as follows,
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{\pi x}{2}=t\to \,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\,dt\implies x=\frac{2}{\pi}t}$$
$$I(n)=\frac{2^{n+1}}{\pi^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{\sinh(t)} \mathrm dt$$
$$\color{red}{\sinh(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}}$$
$$I(n)=\frac{2^{n+2}}{\pi^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{e^t-e^{-t}} \mathrm dt$$
$$I(n)=\frac{2^{n+2}}{\pi^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^ne^{-t}}{1-e^{-2t}} \mathrm dt$$
$$\color{red}{2t=x\implies \,dt=\frac12\,dx\to t=\frac12 x}$$
$$I(n)=\frac{2}{\pi^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^ne^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{1-e^{-x}} \mathrm dx$$
In $(1)$, setting $s-1=n$ and $a=\frac12$,
$$\color{blue}{\displaystyle \zeta \left(n+1,\frac12\right)\,\Gamma (n+1)=\int _{0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{1-e^{-x}}}dx}$$
$$\boxed{\color{green}{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx=\frac{2}{\pi^{n+1}}\zeta \left(n+1,\frac12\right)\,\Gamma (n+1)}}$$
Replace $n\to 2n-1$,
$${\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1
}}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx=\frac{2}{\pi^{2n}}\zeta \left(2n,\frac12\right)\,\Gamma (2n)}$$
Using,
$$\color{red}{\zeta \left(2n,\frac12\right)\,\Gamma (2n)=(2^{2n}-1)\zeta(2n)\Gamma(2n)}$$
$$\boxed{\color{green}{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1
}}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx=\frac{2(2^{2n}-1)\zeta(2n)\Gamma(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}}}$$

For the general case of
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{\sinh \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)} \mathrm dx$$
Using the same approach as @PrincessEev, making the story short
$$I_n=\frac {2 \left(2^{n+1}-1\right) } {\pi ^{n+1} }\,\zeta (n+1)\, \Gamma (n+1)$$ If $n$ is odd, then your sequence

Substitute $\frac{\pi x}2 =-\ln t$
\begin{align}\int_0^\infty &\frac{x^{2k-1} }{\sinh x }{d}x 
= -\left(\frac2\pi\right)^{2k}\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t^2}dt\\
 = &\ \frac{2^{2k+1}}{\pi^{2k}}\bigg( \int_0^1 \frac{t\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t^2}\overset{t^2\to t}{dt}-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t}dt \bigg)\\
 = &\ \frac{2^{2k+1}}{\pi^{2k}}\bigg( \frac1{2^{2k}}-1\bigg) \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t}dt = \frac {2(2^{2k}-1)(2k-1)!}{\pi^{2k}}\zeta(2k)\\
\end{align}
where $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2k-1}t}{1-t}dt=-(2k-1)!\zeta(2k)$

Here's a (somewhat inelegant) proof showing that $I_n$ is the E.G.F. of $\tan t$.
Consider $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{I_k}{(2k-1)!}t^{2k-1}.$$ This is equal to
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)!}\frac{x^{2k-1}t^{2k-1}}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)!}\frac{x^{2k-1}t^{2k-1}}{\sinh(x \frac\pi 2)} \mathrm dx$$
where I interchanged the sum and integral. The infinite sum equals $\frac{\sinh(xt)}{\sinh(x\frac{\pi}{2})}$, so we are left with $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sinh(xt)}{\sinh(x\pi/2)}dx$$
We can then use the exponential form of $\sinh$ and the substitution $e^{\pi x}\to x$ to get that this equals $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{\pi}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{\pi}}}{1-x}dx\underbrace{=}_{1/x\to x}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{\pi}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{\pi}}}{1-x}dx$$
With $1/x\to x$, the bounds of integration change to $0$ to $1$, but interestingly, nothing else changes. We can then use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ for $|x|<1$, so we then have $$\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1\left(x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{\pi}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{\pi}}\right)x^{n}dx.$$ The integral equals $\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{\pi}+n+1}-\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{\pi}+n+1}$. After some rearranging, we are left with $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\frac{1}{\pi n+\pi/2-t}-\frac{1}{\pi n+\pi/2+t}\right).$$
In terms of the digamma function, this is $$\frac{\psi(N+3/2-t/\pi)-\psi(N+3/2+t/\pi)+\psi(1/2+t/\pi)-\psi(1/2-t/\pi)}{\pi}.$$
$\psi(z)\sim \ln(z)-\frac{1}{2z}$ for large $z$, so the first two terms basically turn into $\ln(N+3/2-t/\pi)-\ln(N+3/2+t/\pi)\to 0$. We then use the digamma reflection formula to get $$\frac{\pi\cot(\pi(1/2-t/\pi))}{\pi}=\tan(t)$$
